# Running multiple rsync executions in script

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to run multiple rsync commands from a bash script but only the first one fires. I've tried linking the commands with `&&` and `;` but neither work.

```
#! /bin/bash
rsync -ahPr --delete-excluded --exclude='.DS_Store' --exclude=Caches/ --ignore-errors --stats --log-file=$LOGFILE --files-from=$FILESFROM ~/$SOURCE /Volumes/$DEST &&
rsync -avh --progress ~/.profile /Volumes/$DEST/_profile/profile &&
rsync -avh --progress ~/.gitconfig /Volumes/$DEST/_profile/gitconfig &&
rsync -avh --progress ~/.ssh/ /Volumes/$DEST/_profile/ssh/ &&
rsync -avh --progress ~/.vim/ /Volumes/$DEST/_profile/vim/
```

I'm doing the last 4 commands as seperate ones because I'm renaming the files/directories on the fly—not sure if there's a better way to do this?

I'm executing the script with `bash -x myscript.sh` to see if it comes up with any errors, but no.

Comment: Remove all `&&` from your script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running

`rsync && rsync`

will start the second rsync after the first one completes. You want

`rsync&`

Explanation:

`a && b`

a runs, b runs next only if a competes successfuly

`a || b`

a runs, b runs next only if a completes UNsuccessfully

`a; b`

a runs, b runs next no matter the success

`a& b`

a runs, gets sent into the background. This is equivalent to running a, typing ctrl-Z and the running bg

So if you want your programs to run at the same time, replace the &&s with single &

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the spacing needed. Regardless it's still not working. If I comment out the first larger rsync command, the remaining 4 work fine. Do I have a timing issue?

Comment: OK, I've swapped the longer command from first to last. They now all fire correctly. I can only presume that there is a timing issue, but would appreciate it if someone could confirm this?

Comment: Not a timing issue. Since the last four commands don't execute if the long one is run first, but do if the long one is running  last, and the next command in the chain only execute if the previous one succeeds (due to the double-'&'s), the issue is the long command exits with an error. (@Facebook - this? newbsauce here)

Comment: The first was indeed having an error. I cleared the error and changed everything to a; b. It works now. Thanks @Peter Berbec

Comment: Glad to help! I've gotten help here dozens of times, but never created an account. I feel warm and fuzzy!